# Using third-party apps on a high DPI (Retina) display

Tags: display, pixel-density

What settings do I have to change such that third-party apps have the same scaling and font size as native elementary apps?

[image]

And where is the right place to file bug reports about this? Qt/KDE for individual apps? Launchpad for elementary?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1455227

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is something that has to be fixed by those app or toolkit developers. For example, Google Chrome only just recently started to support HiDPI. Most Gtk3 apps (like the ones we ship by default) should get HiDPI support more-or-less for free with only minor issues to work through. But since HiDPI is still relatively new, not all application toolkits fully support it yet.

Each 3rd party app is going to have it's own way to track bug reports, and some proprietary apps might not accept bug reports at all. The best way to find an app's bug tracker is either through their official website or through a search engine.

Comment: Is there a way to disable High-DPI and use Full-HD? It is not really usable in this state. :(

Comment: @davidak You can try manually setting your scaling factor in dconf editor at `org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling factor`

Answer (score 4):

When launching Chromium web apps you can pass the flag `--force-device-scale-factor=2` to get properly scaled content on HiDPI.

Ideally you should add it to the respective `.desktop` file of the app so that you can have the launcher in the dock or start it via Slingshot.

For example:

```
$ cat  ~/.local/share/applicationschrome-f*-Default.desktop

#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Postman
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --force-device-scale-factor=2 --profile-directory=Default --app-id=fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Icon=chrome-fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
```

Comment: This also works for the Spotify client